# Get Userlist with rolename in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In My spring boot Application, I want to see total userlist like below:

| username | role |
| --- | --- |
| admin | ADMIN |

But i got like:

| username | role |
| --- | --- |
| admin | [com.test.springCRUD.model.Role@3e39aaf6] |

**My User model:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @Column(name="user_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private boolean enabled;
        
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name ="users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name="user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name="role_id"))
        private Set<Role> roles=new HashSet<>();
```

**Role model:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "roles")
    public class Role {
        @Id
        @Column(name="role_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
```

**UserService Class:**

```
    @Service
    public class UserServices {
        
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        
        public List<User> listAll(){
            return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping("/userlist")
        public String viewUserList(Model model) {
            List<User> listUsers = userServices.listAll();
            model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);
            return "userList";
        }
```

**thymleaf page:**

```
    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="user : ${listUsers}">
                        <td th:text="${user.id}">User ID</td>
                        <td th:text="${user.username}">User Name</td>
                        <td th:text="${user.roles}">User Role</td>
    
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

How to get userlist with rolename.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a similar project.

- 'roles' is defined as a Set of Roles, so you are seeing the identifiers of that object, rather than the values.
- You will need to iterate through the roles themselves if the intent is to display the list of names of roles.
- Also remember, the role has a name and Id since it in itself is an entity/model, so you will want to iterate the roles and show role name, something like:

  ```
   - <el  th:each="role : ${user.getRoles()}"/>
   - <el th:text="${role.getName()}"/>
  ```

  If you are liking the Table, I would recommend a span for each role name.
  There are alternatives depending on how you want it shown. You may also do this in your controller or UserDetails class depending on what the desired functionality/application or display is beyond verifying it within a thymeleaf page for users or Admins.